# How to assign the custom cell in UITableView using Enum in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, enums

I have got a UITableView which has got 2 custom cells. The type of the custom cell is defined by the key "JourneyType" which we are getting from the web service. So if the Journey Type is Solo we need to show the cell with SoloCustomCell and if the journey type is Group we need to show the cell with GroupCustomCell. I am in the idea of using enum for determining the Switch case for allocating the cells. I have defined the enum like this:

```
  enum SubscriptionTripType: Int {
  case oneWayTrip = 1
  case roundTrip
  case splitShift

  var value: String {
    switch self {
    case .oneWayTrip:
      return NSLocalizedString("One way", comment: "")
    case .roundTrip:
      return NSLocalizedString("Round trip", comment: "")
    case .splitShift:
      return NSLocalizedString("Split shift", comment: "")
    }
  }
}
```

Now in the cellForRowIndex I have defined the code like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let subscription = mySubscriptionDetails[indexPath.row]
    switch subscription.journeyType{
    case 0:
      let proposePoolcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subscriptionCell", for: indexPath) as? MySubscriptionCustomCell
      configure(cell: proposePoolcell!, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
      return proposePoolcell!
    case 1:
      let splitShiftCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "splitShiftCell", for: indexPath) as? SplitShiftSubscriptionCell
      return splitShiftCell!
    default:break
    }
  }
```

Subscription.journeyType is the value which we are getting from the Web service. Currently subscription array contains 8 elements each having the journeyType. So we need to check the case based on the enum defined at the above. How to populate the cell for specific journey type based on the Enum.

Comment: What is your problem?  What is happening?  Why are you using the associate int value in your csee instead of the enumeration values? Are you asking how to turn the int from the web service into a enumeration value?  If so, use the rawValue

Comment: @Paulw11 See i am getting the values of Journey Type from webservice as "One-Way". So i need to check if the value is One-Way i should place the custom cell of "One-Way" else another cell.

Comment: Are you asking how to initialise an enumeration value from a string rawValue?  Have you read the chapter in the Swift Book on enumerations?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes i am asking about the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to initialise an enumeration value using a string from a web services API.

The easiest way to do that is to use a string raw value with your enumeration.

```
enum SubscriptionTripType: String {
    case oneWayTrip = "One Way"
    case roundTrip = "Round Trip"
    case splitShift = "Split Shift"
}
```

Now, you can initialise an instance by saying something like:

```
if let tripType = SubscriptionTripType(rawValue:"One Way") {
    print(tripType)
} else {
    print("Invalid trip type")
}
```

You can then use the trip type to determine a tableview cell and as your `switch` statement can be exhaustive you don't need a `default` case

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let subscription = mySubscriptionDetails[indexPath.row]
    switch subscription.journeyType {
    case .oneWayTrip:
      let proposePoolcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subscriptionCell", for: indexPath) as! MySubscriptionCustomCell
      configure(cell: proposePoolcell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
      return proposePoolcell

    case .roundTrip:
      let roundTripCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "roundTripCell", for: indexPath) as! MyRoundTripCustomCell
      configure(cell: proposePoolcell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
      return roundTripCell

    case .splitShift:
      let splitShiftCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "splitShiftCell", for: indexPath) as! SplitShiftSubscriptionCell
      return splitShiftCell!
    }
}
```